# DropDownList - Retrieving Data from Database - Disappear After AutoPostBack

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

My `DropDownList1` retrieves a data from a column in the database, on the same page, I have another `DropDownList2`  that when Selecting a value, it will fire an `AutoPostBack`, the problem I am running into is,

if I select a value from `DropDownList1`, the value will be un-selected when the `AutoPostBack` happens, how can I make the `DropDownList` keeps the selected Value when an `AutoPostBack` is fired?

Thank you

Comment: are you handle dropdown_selectedchange event to verify

Answer (score 1):

You must be binding the `DropDownList1` in `Page_Load` event. in that case, you should make sure that you should bind it only for first time and not every time by using `IsPostBack` property like below, otherwise every time it will get data from DB and will re-populate your dropdownlist.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    If(!IsPostBack)
    {
      //Bind DropDownList1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the viewstate is set to True so the values stored in the dropdown get reset from the viewstate, as well as the control's selected value.